# Is there a way to combine SQL with FQL (Facebook Query Language)

Tags: mysql, fql.multiquery

Is there a way to combine SQL with FQL. 
I am talking about something like FQL multiqueries.

This is my sample code.

//Here I take data from a SQL database

$result_user_pages = mysql_query("SELECT Page_ID FROM user_fanpage WHERE User_ID='$uid'");

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_user_pages))
{
     $user_page_ID[$m]    = $row['Page_ID'] ;
     $m++;
}
```

//Here I pass '$user_page_ID' array into a for loop and call facebook api

for ($i=0; $i
        $query1         =   "SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id='$user_page_ID[$i]'";
        $query2         =   "SELECT fromid,text from comment WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #query1)";

```
    $queries        =   '{
                           "query1": "' . $query1 . '",
                           "query2": "' . $query2 . '"
                         }';
    $attachment = array("method"=>"fql.multiquery","queries"=>$queries,'access_token'=>$access_token);
    $ret_code = $facebook->api($attachment);
```

}

If '$user_page_ID' has 10 elements, api is called 10 times.Therefore sometime it gives me a connection time out error message.If there is a away to combine sql query with fql(like fql multiqueries), I can avoid this error message. 
Can any one tell me whether there is a way to do this or any other solution...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with the restrictions that are in place

Comment: Sorry mate.I think I didn't get your answer.Does that simply mean I can't combine SQL with FQL?

Comment: you can not do, different systems